# Initialization of static variables

Tags: c++, c, static

Can anyone please tell me when the `static` variables/functions are allocated memory and in which memory segment? i.e. `static global variable, static member variable, static local variable` etc all are initialized once before the beginning of program and all retains its values?

Furthermore, If `Class MyClass` has static variable `count`, when I declare `MyClass obj` in main, then `MyClass` object is created and count is given memory, If I declared `MyClass obj2`, what happens in terms of memory? Is there any `count` in `obj2` which refers to the `count` of `obj1`? Or there is only separate memory allocation. Hope so that I am able to clearly ask the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When we declare a member of a class as `static` it means no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the `static` member. **It exists even though no objects of the static data member's class exist**.

A `static` member is shared by all objects of the class.

> If I declared `MyClass obj2`, what happens in terms of memory? Is there any `count` in `obj2` which refers to the `count` of `obj1`?

Yes. There is only one `count` for all objects. This test program would explain this a bit clear;

```
class Something
{
    public:
    static int s_nValue;
};

int Something::s_nValue = 1;

int main()
{
    Something cFirst;
    cFirst.s_nValue = 2;

    Something cSecond;
    std::cout << cSecond.s_nValue;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2
```

Because `s_nValue` is a `static` member variable, `s_nValue` is shared between all objects of the class. **Consequently, `cFirst.s_nValue` is the same as `cSecond.s_nValue`**.

> Furthermore, If Class `MyClass` has `tatic` variable count, when I declare `MyClass obj` in main, then `MyClass` object is created and `count` is given memory

No. In fact, `count` exists even if there are no objects of the class have been instantiated!

Comment: Just little bit of confusion. You said that **it exists even though no object of static member's class exist**, it means that it exists when program starts, and there is some hidden pointer in class which points to the `static` member. Sorry if i am thinking in wrong direction.

Comment: You are right but I am not sure about: *and there is some hidden pointer in class which points to the static member.*

Comment: Either it is `static global veriable`, or `static member variable`, or `static local variable` in all cases, they are created before the beginning of program? Class object does not need to exist?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` can probably be seen as somewhat "overloaded".

The following usage-options are all viable:

- Static local variables
- Static global variables
- Static member variables
- Static global functions
- Static member functions

---

### Variables:

In terms of runtime, all types of static variables are essentially the same. They all reside in the **data-section** of the program, and their addresses remain constant throughout the execution of the program. So the only difference between them is during compilation, in the scope of declaration:

- Static local variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the function
- Static global variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the file
- Static member variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the class

---

### Functions:

In terms of runtime, all types of functions (static and non-static) are essentially the same. They all reside in the **code-section** of the program, and their addresses remain constant throughout the execution of the program. So the only difference between them is during compilation, in the scope of declaration:

- Static global function: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the file
- Static member function: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the class

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` has different meaning depending on the context it is used in. `static` variables are allocated on the heap and their lifetime extends across the entire run of the program.

1. A static global variable is same as a global variable except that the `static` keyword limits the scope of the variable to the file containing it only. This is called file linkage or internal linkage.
2. A static member variable is created when the class containing it is defined. This means it can be accessed using the class's name. This variable is shared across all instances of the class.
3. A static local variable has the same lifetime as that of a static global variable except that its scope is the immediate block containing it.
4. When a function is qualified with the `static` keyword, this means that the scope of the function is the file containing it only. The function cannot be called by a function in another file. This is, again, called file scope or internal linkage.